# How to delete global symlink without deleting local dependencies in npm?

Tags: node.js, npm

I develop npm package. In order to be able to use local version of npm package I use `npm link` - this command creates global symlink to my package. After work with my package I would like to delete global symlink. 
I found the command: `npm unlink`

But this command is alias to `npm uninstall`, so when it is run in package root folder it uninstall all local dependencies of my package also.

How to delete global symlink to my package without uninstalling all local dependencies?

Answer (score 2):

You can't do it.

`link` just create `syslink` to that module, is not copy.

So you can `unlink` and install it again.